# Permanently save reference to ID objects in Python

Tags: python, scripting

I am writing a custom render engine, and I need to store permanent reference to ID types such as Object, Material, Image. But since these are likely to change when you do Ctrl + Z, or do some other actions, I can't just store a usual reference to the object.

I know this can be done in properties using a pointer property. Can I simulate this behavior or instantiate the property somehow without actually assigning them as a custom properties, just in regular python code?

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do, but usually you would work with the dependency graph. There shouldn't be any need to store a reference to any particular object, material, image, etc.

Comment: I am caching the render bathes based on which object they belong to. I don't want to reconstruct every batch on every draw call. And the reference is required to get uniforms from custom properties assigned to the object.

Comment: Sound like you may have chosen an abstraction that isn't well suited for integration with Blender. You could use the unique names to reference the objects an check whether or not they still exist.

Comment: That's my current approach. That's the only abstraction I can think of in that case, sadly. Since it is gonna be an OpenGL-based renderer for viewport purposes only.